# Как запретить повторную регистрацию с одного ip в течение часа?

Tags: php, ip, регистрация

Есть форма регистрации. Время регистрации передаётся на обработчик из поля:

```
<input type="hidden" name="time_reg" value="<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

IP получается из `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Моё решение такое: я получаю из формы данные нового пользователя, сравниваю его IP с имеющимися в базе MySQL, если находится совпадение, сравниваю время регистрации, если прошло меньше 3600 секунд, отправляю его подождать.

Но когда пользователей с одним и тем же IP в базе больше одного, сравнивать время регистрации становится сложнее.

Кроме того, если данные из формы отправляются с помощью ajax, страница не перезагружается, и время регистрации в инпуте не обновляется!!

Короче, интуитивно чувствую, что моё решение - отстой (( Подскажите, наверняка ведь есть что-то более простое и изящное?

Comment: А почему вы не обновите время регистрации в форме в случае success вашего ajax запроса? Ну и можно забить человеку куки, которые будут действительны определённое время. Дополнительная мера.

Comment: вы не сказали какая у вас база. все современные базы обладают хорошими возможностями поиска того, что вам нужно. любая SQL база легко может для вас получить максимальное время для указанного ip, а именно оно вам и нужно. а уж взаимодействие частей вашей страницы - это сугубо ваше дело. раз используете ajax так пусть запрос к серверу вернет нужное время и вы его положите в нужный инпут. правда окончательный контроль времени все равно должен быть на сервере ибо на клиенте все что угодно могут подделать

Comment: @n.osennij да, но это всё смахивает на "костыли". куки могут быть просто отключены. нужно какое-то универсальное и простое решение

Comment: @Mike, да, виноват - база MySQL

Comment: @humster_spb, согласен с Mike о использовании SQL базы данных.  Но  я бы посоветовал использовать в таком случае Memcache либо Redis. Да, будет заполнятся ОП, но не пространство БД. 
Вы себе сможете проставить время жизни ключей-значений без особых усилий.

Comment: ну так `select max(time) from table where ip='x.x.x.x'` вернет вам макссимальное время регистрации с этого ip. дальше его вычтите из текущего и убедитесь прошло заданное время или нет и если нет - вернете клиенту ошибку. А зачем вам на клиенте нужен input со временем мне сложно предположить

Comment: @Mike, если не сложно, напишите в виде ответа конкретный код - я так обрывками не очень понимаю, что именно и где именно надо сделать. Я отправляю время из инпута потому что не знаю, как иначе занести в базу время регистрации ))

Comment: из клиента время регистрации передавать нельзя. клиент может как угодно поправить передаваемые вам данные. И это получается не время регистрации, а время открытия страницы в браузере. Может человек пошел попить кофе, вернулся и только через час нажал "зарегистрироваться", а время то у вас осталось час назад ... У MySQL есть функция `now()` возвращающая текущее время, так что когда вы вставляете запись вы не из php время передавайте а пусть БД сама его получает `insert into table(..., reg_time) values(..., now())`

Comment: Вы потеряете пользователей с общим серым IP. Не нужно. Кука тоже не нужна - она у вас уже есть - это сессия. От ботов мало-мальски поможет `reCaptcha`. Если действительно критично - нужно ограничивать количеством имеющихся на руках симок. Проще почтовых ящиков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, получать время из формы - это, конечно, не есть хорошо. В php имеется ряд функций для работы со временем, я выбрал вариант, который возвращает мне timestamp:

```
$time_reg = strtotime('now');
```

IP, как уже было сказано в вопросе, получается так:

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Осталось выбрать из базы время последнего зарегистрированного с одного и того же ip

```
"SELECT time_reg FROM users WHERE ip = '$user_ip' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

и оценить, достаточно ли прошло секунд/минут/часов для повторной регистрации.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша "защита" отстой. Она будет мешать нормальным пользователям (ipv4 кончаются, у многих сейчас серый ip) и не большая помеха ботам (прокси листы продаются за копейки). Прикрутите лучше капчу от google или другую.

Answer (score 0):

Сохраните время последней регистрации в куки.
Не-хакер не догадается почистить куки или зайти с другого браузера, а против хакера надежного решения не существует. 
Можно конечно кроме IP-адреса собрать другие данные, тип и версия ОС и т.п., но ведь и IP-адрес не составит труда замаскировать через прокси.

Во вторых, ограничивать нужно не повторную регистрацию, а скажем 20-ю с одного IP - пусть себе заводит чувак 20 эккаунтов в час если хочет, думаю эти эккаунты не по мегабаксу стОят.